# The submenu doesn't show up when hover the mouse

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. I don't know what wrong with the code as when I hover the mouse over 'About us', the submenu didn't show up. I did make the submenu display:none and then when hover, it display: block but nothing happen. Thanks for your help

```css
#nav_menu{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#nav_menu li{
    float: left;
}
#nav_menu li a{
    display: block;
    width: 160px;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #800000;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav_menu .current{
    color: yellow;
}
#nav_menu #sub_menu{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}
#nav_menu #sub_menu:hover{
    display: block;
}
#nav_menu #sub_menu li a{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav_menu">
        <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="speakers.html">Speakers</a></li>
        <li><a href="luncheons.html">Luncheons</a></li>
        <li><a href="tickets.html">Tickets</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
            <ul id="sub_menu">
                <li><a href="">Our History</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Board of Directors</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Past Speakers</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact Information</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display a submenu when hovering, you need to write like this:

```
#nav_menu li:hover #sub_menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Because you are accessing the #sub_menu selector. Also, you need to add `position: relative` the selector `#nav_menu li` is relevant for the correctness of your `position: absolute` of the selector `#nav_menu #sub_menu`. And add `padding: 0` for the selector of the same selector `#nav_menu #sub_menu`, in order to align it under the main menu.

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav_menu{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#nav_menu li{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#nav_menu li a{
    display: block;
    width: 160px;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #800000;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav_menu .current{
    color: yellow;
}
#nav_menu #sub_menu{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

/*#nav_menu #sub_menu:hover{
    display: block;
}*/

#nav_menu li:hover #sub_menu{
    display: block;
}

#nav_menu #sub_menu li a{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav_menu">
        <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="speakers.html">Speakers</a></li>
        <li><a href="luncheons.html">Luncheons</a></li>
        <li><a href="tickets.html">Tickets</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
            <ul id="sub_menu">
                <li><a href="">Our History</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Board of Directors</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Past Speakers</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact Information</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

My method is a little different and shorter with the **animation** opening and closing for the submenu, I used the `scale` instead of `display` for animation;

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav_menu{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#nav_menu li{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#nav_menu li a{
    display: block;
    width: 160px;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #800000;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav_menu .current{
    color: yellow;
}
#nav_menu #sub_menu{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    transform : scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: top;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}



#nav_menu li:hover #sub_menu{
  transform: scaleY(1);
}


#nav_menu #sub_menu li a{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav_menu">
        <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="speakers.html">Speakers</a></li>
        <li><a href="luncheons.html">Luncheons</a></li>
        <li><a href="tickets.html">Tickets</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
            <ul id="sub_menu">
                <li><a href="">Our History</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Board of Directors</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Past Speakers</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact Information</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```